# Cck date field save not working properly

Tags: 6, datetime

I am saving a date field and when i print the value as 
`print_r($node->mydate[0]['value']);` it is printing only year `2012`. This problem is only for one field. If i adds a new date type field in that content type that works perfectly.I checked all actions and in my custom code but still not found anything wrong with that. If i update timestamp value with my sql query using db_query that still have problem. I can't delete my field because of my previous content. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem just by [renaming](http://drupal.org/project/cck_field_rename) the field. I couldn't found any reason what the problem was. I didn't found anything related to this in my custom code either.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the granularity on the field isn't set to year only. You can edit this by going to `admin/structure/types/manage/[CONTENT TYPE]/fields` and selecting "edit" on the appropriate field.

[image]

Comment: I am on D6 and I added the select list widget of date. I added year, date and month. With the same settings the other field is working fine.